# HUAWEI ML Kit uses the multiclass image segmentation capability to process a bitmap, but an error occurs

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

anything else wrong. What are the possible causes? Here is the detailed log information:

```js
2020-04-23 10:52:35.924 10773-10773/com.huawei.hms.core.demo W/System.err: com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.common.MLException: Mlals result is error
2020-04-23 10:52:35.924 10773-10773/com.huawei.hms.core.demo W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.productvisionsearch.cloud.MLRemoteProductVisionSearchAnalyzer.handleResult(MLRemoteProductVisionSearchAnalyzer.java:249)
2020-04-23 10:52:35.924 10773-10773/com.huawei.hms.core.demo W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.productvisionsearch.cloud.MLRemoteProductVisionSearchAnalyzer.access$800(MLRemoteProductVisionSearchAnalyzer.java:83)
2020-04-23 10:52:35.924 10773-10773/com.huawei.hms.core.demo W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.productvisionsearch.cloud.MLRemoteProductVisionSearchAnalyzer$1.call(MLRemoteProductVisionSearchAnalyzer.java:161)
2020-04-23 10:52:35.924 10773-10773/com.huawei.hms.core.demo W/System.err: at com.huawei.hms.mlsdk.productvisionsearch.cloud.MLRemoteProductVisionSearchAnalyzer$1.call(MLRemoteProductVisionSearchAnalyzer.java:123)
2020-04-23 10:52:35.924 10773-10773/com.huawei.hms.core.demo W/System.err: at com.huawei.hmf.tasks.a.j$1.run(Unknown Source:4)
2020-04-23 10:52:35.924 10773-10773/com.huawei.hms.core.demo W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-04-23 10:52:35.924 10773-10773/com.huawei.hms.core.demo W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-04-23 10:52:35.924 10773-10773/com.huawei.hms.core.demo W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by your log, the error cause is that the relevant algorithm model is currently unavailable in the cloud. As a result, an error is reported when you try to access cloud services from a device.

With deep learning as the core technology, ML Kit uses the image recognition and search functions to implement personalized product search services. A specific search information library needs to be generated based on product images. If you want to use cloud services, please provide the base library containing product information to the HUAWEI ML Kit team. The team performs model training based on the base library and then deploys the model in the cloud for you to call it from the device. To contact the HUAWEI ML Kit team, please send an email to mlkit@huawei.com.